Strategy to keep adding on buy signals
I am working on an index strategy where I want to keep adding X amount whenever the close is Y% down from 1 month high. This is just experiment, basically kind of smart DIP strategy, I will exit only at the last trading day just to check the performance. I tried searching sample scripts where I can keep adding the money but sell once today only but no luck.
Can anyone please help me here? Below is the script which I am working on.
//@version=5
strategy(title="Index SIP Strategy", shorttitle="Index SIP Strategy", overlay = true, pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,default_qty_value=100, precision=2, process_orders_on_close  = true)


// ====== BUY LOGIC

length   = input.int(22, minval=1)
h        = ta.highest(high, length)
percDip   = input.int(5, minval=1)


source = close
downPer= ((h - close)/h)*100

diffConditionBuy = false
if downPer > percDip
    diffConditionBuy := true

// TOPUP POINT --  
if diffConditionBuy == true
    strategy.entry("x", strategy.long, comment="Buy")

// ====== SELL LOGIC
isLastTradingDay = ((timenow-time)<300000000)
diffConditionSell = isLastTradingDay

// EXIT POINT
if diffConditionSell == true
    strategy.close_all("Exit today")

